# ログインするとエラーがでる

Tags: laravel-5

Laravel5.5のログインについての質問です。

php artisan make:authのコマンドで生成された認証を実装したのですが、ログインを押すとこのようなエラーがでます。なぜでしょうか？

```
Method [validate] does not exist on [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController].
```

↓ここの部分が赤くなっています↓

```
throw new BadMethodCallException("Method [{$method}] does not exist on [".get_class($this).'].');
```

このエラーは何を言ってて、どうしたら解決できるかご教授ください。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: `validate`というメソッドは`App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController`に存在しません　といういうメッセージです。

Comment: 遅くなりました。validateメソッドを追加して、色々いじっていたら自分の飛ばしたいページに飛ぶようになりました。ありがとうございました。